# Unable to install request package for python 3

Tags: python, linux

The message that I get when typing
"pip3 install request":

```
Collecting request
Collecting setupfiles (from request)
Collecting post (from request)
Collecting get (from request)
Collecting query-string (from get->request)
Collecting public (from query-string->get->request)
Installing collected packages: setupfiles, post, public, query-string, get, request
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/vapour3005/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/vapour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setupfiles-0.0.50.dist-info'
```

In case of "sudo pip3 install request":

```
The directory '/home/vapour/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
The directory '/home/vapour/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting request
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/request/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for request
```

When I write "python3" in the terminal then I get the following message:

```
Python 3.6.2rc1 (default, Jul 11 2017, 02:53:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

If I launch virtual environment and try to install request then I get that

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting request
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/request/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for request
```

What should I do?

UPD:

Now it is installed globally but
In virtual environment I get

$ pip3 install requests

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Collecting requests

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests

Comment: Do you actually mean to install [request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/request) and not [request**s**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)?

Comment: `pip3 install requests` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#pipenv-install-requests

Comment: Thanks, I falied. But I still have troubles

Comment: "Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available." ?  Your python installation is broken. It should have the ssl module by default.  Are you using your linux system's default python interpreter or your own?

Comment: Do I need to install openssl-devel?

Comment: I downloaded it from official site. I don't remember whether I changed smth I'm not a professional programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what are you trying to install is the "requests" package

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32069811)